# Android PIE API 28 - 'SQLite: No Such Table Error'

Tags: android

[Asset folder shows the queston mark pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ngLj.jpg)  I have a database saved in my apps assets folder and I copy the database using the below code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String DB_NAME = "BD.db";
        private EditText txtUsername;
        private EditText txtPassword;
        private SQLiteDatabase database;
        private  ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;
        private com.it.bdrelease.Log  errorlog;
     private String errorMessage;
     private  GlobalClass global;
     private String strSalespersonID;
     private Cursor cursor;
     private SharedPreference sharedPreference;
     private Activity context = this;

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable shape = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonbackground);
    Button loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    loginbutton.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.headbg));
    actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>Business Development </font>"));
    dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    addListenerOnOkButton();
    txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    txtUsername.setText("xxxxx@hotmail.com");
 }
 public void addListenerOnOkButton()
{
    final Context context = this;
    Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

            if(txtUsername.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && txtPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
          {
              String strUserName = txtUsername.getText().toString().trim();
              String strPassword = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
              cursor= database.query("tblUsers", null, "UserName='" + strUserName + "' and Password='" + strPassword  + "'" , null, null, null, null);
                if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
                {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else
                {       cursor.moveToFirst();
                        String SalespersonID =cursor.getString(0);
                        String SalespersonName = cursor.getString(2);
                        sharedPreference.save(context, SalespersonID);
                        GlobalClass global;
                        global=((GlobalClass)getApplicationContext());
                        global.setSalespersonId(SalespersonID);
                        global.setName(SalespersonName);
                        GlobalClass.SalespersonID=SalespersonID;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, BdActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        clear();
                }
              }
        else
        {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter username and password.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error encountered:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                              }
              finally
               {
                   cursor.close();
               }
         }
   });
}
public void clear()
{
    txtUsername.setText("");
    txtPassword.setText("");
    txtUsername.requestFocus();
}
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  //super.onBackPressed();
 // openQuitDialog();
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tested ok ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //database.close();
    finish();
 }
```

}
and  my DBHelper class:

```
public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, 2);
    this.context = context;

    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
    //DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/"; 
    DB_NAME = databaseName;
    openDataBase();
}

public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");

    }

    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;
}
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException
{
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    try
    {
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }
        //return database;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
      {
             Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while openDataBase");
             strSalespersonID = global.getId();
             errorMessage = e.toString();
             errorlog.LogError("1", "ExternalDbOpenHelper", "onCreate",  errorMessage.toString(), "", strSalespersonID);
      }   
    return database;
}



/*

 @Override
 public synchronized void close() {
  if (database != null)
   database.close();
  super.close();
 }
 /*
public SQLiteDatabase CloseDataBase() throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
      {
             strSalespersonID = global.getId();
             errorMessage = e.toString();
             errorlog.LogError("1", "CloseDatabase", "onCreate",  errorMessage.toString(), "", strSalespersonID);
      }
    return database;        
}
 */

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
```

}

The above code runs without problem in Android 7  but when you try to query the database you get an SQLite: No such table exception.
This issue only occurs in Android P(API 28), all earlier versions of Android work correctly.
How can i resolve this?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to be able to help you as the code you've provided is too long and detailed - instead, please consider replacing the code you've copied and pasted with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such that the problem can easily be identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forgot to close db before copy it from asset.

```
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        this.close(); //Should close here
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Asaduzzman  thanks for reply after i checked my console show this error:  E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '//data//data//com.neotransit.bdrelease//databases//BD.db'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:211)

Comment: Faild to open database

Comment: SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '//data//data//com.neotransit.bdrelease//databases//BD.db'

Comment: Android 7 my code working fine and i try to update Android 9 can't open db. what's wrong?

Comment: Try using single slash instead of double slash

Comment: After i tried single slash it shows : Failed to open database '/data/data/com.neotransit.bdrelease/databases/BD.db'

Comment: In my Asset folder shows the question mark? what is this?

Comment: Thanks Asaduzzaman after delete my db in the asset folder and  copy from source and pate in asset folder  It works fine. But cleaning my console after run my app the console shows can't open database. What is this reason? Please clarify me.But apps work fine fetching data from db.